# PHP not echoing array to display usernames in 000webhost

Tags: php, xml

So I was creating a login or not kind of display in php using this code:

```
<?php
if(file_exists('account/users/' . $_SESSION['username'] . '.xml')){
    echo "<a style='float: right;' href='account'><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></a>";
}
else {
    echo "<a style='float: right;' href='account'>Login or Register</a>";
}
?>
```

But instead it says:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /storage/ssd3/099/21080099/public_html/index.php on line 22

I tried adding a space from here

```
echo "<a style='float: right;' href='account'><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></a>";
```

but it says this:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /storage/ssd3/099/21080099/public_html/index.php on line 22

Comment: Why doing this - <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?> ? PHP statement is not closed yet and I don't think its required. you can simply use $_SESSION['username'];

Comment: Can you print $_SESSION['username'] using print_r($_SESSION['username'] ? is it single username or multiple usernames?

Comment: That error means that `$_SESSION['username']` contains an array, not a string.

Comment: Why do you try to put PHP code **into** an `echo` statement? Also, how is this problem related to XML?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `<?php echo` inside strings. You use that when you're outside the PHP code, in plain text or HTML that's being output, and you want to insert a variable or expression into the output.

When you're already inside a string, just put the variable directly, inside `{}` when necessary.

```
    echo "<a style='float: right;' href='account'>{$_SESSION['username']}</a>";
```

If you get the `Array to string conversion` error from this, it means that `$_SESSION['username']` is an array. Either you need to fix how you're assigning the session variable (it's not clear why you would need it to be an array) or add the appropriate index when printing it.

See the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for more details on parsing variable substitutions inside double-quoted strings. Note that this is not available when using single quotes around the string, then you use concatenation with the `.` operator.

Comment: The use of `{}` applies only if strings get evaluated in `double quotes` but `not in single`. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446245/3710053